# Windows Phone Toast Notification with multiple lines

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I am working on a Toast Notification app for Windows Phone 8.

I am able to receive the toast notification with single line of data which includes the Title and whatever content can be displayed on the single line.

But anything that goes beyond the scope of the first line is not displayed in the notification.

I know that the character limit for Toast notifications is around 40 chars and I am keeping the length of the text below this limit.

I have also tried including the '\n' sequence for new line. But it makes no difference.

Can anyone please help me to display the toast notification in multiple lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't display a multi-line Toast Notification as they are meant to be short. You can, however, display more information once the user taps on your notification.

Comment: thanks for your response! What you say appears to be correct. But is it mentioned in any doc? Just so that i can use it as a reference in future.

Comment: @user1122549 Well, it is not mentioned that you can or cannot use multiple lines in a toast notification in their documentation. Check out the toast notification guidelines here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx

Comment: @Raz Harush There is templates for multi line notifications. Check this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype

Comment: @slobodans This relates to Windows 8 and not WP8

Comment: Its mentioned that you can not use multi line in phone in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Windows Phone, but in Windows 8 you just need to use a different xml template. With templates 01 and 02 the lines are automatically wrapped.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype

Answer (score 0):

You can use: **Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType.ToastText04**

```
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText04);
var strings = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
strings[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Title"));
strings[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("First text line"));
strings[2].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Second text line"));

var notification = new ToastNotification(toastXml);            Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
```

Comment: Does this work with Windows **Phone** or just Windows 8?